# GKLeaderboard's timeScope does nothing?

Tags: ios, ios7, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I am trying to make a leaderboard using GameCenter on iOS7 that shows only scores submitted in the last week.

I am aware that with iOS7 the use of timescope when opening the gamecenter view controller has been deprecated, but every post I find on this suggests building a leaderboard within the game to get around this.

We have our own leaderboards implemented in game which we fetch using loadScoresWithCompletionHandler, but the timeScope settings still does not appear to work. What ever I set it to, I receive the best score of all time for the user, not the best sore in the last day / week.

Has anyone else found this or does it work for everyone else? I confirm the score is wrong be looking at the "date" on any received GKScores.

The code in question is below:

```
const char* szName("LeaderboardName_Week1");
NSString* pxLeaderboardName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:szName];
GKLeaderboardTimeScope eTimeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
GKLeaderboard* leaderboardViewer = [[[GKLeaderboard alloc] init] autorelease];
if (leaderboardViewer)
{
    [leaderboardViewer setIdentifier: pxLeaderboardName];
    [leaderboardViewer setTimeScope: eTimeScope];
    [leaderboardViewer setRange: NSMakeRange(1, 100)];
    [leaderboardViewer setPlayerScope: (bFriendsOnly)?GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeFriendsOnly:GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal];

    [leaderboardViewer loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* scores, NSError* error)
     {
         if (error || !scores)
         {
             NSLog(@"GameKit Score retrieval Error:\n%@", error);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"GameKit Score retrieval complete, %d scores. Retrieving player names.", (u_int)scores.count);

             GKScore* playerScore = leaderboardViewer.localPlayerScore;

             u_int uIndex2;
             for (uIndex2 = 0; uIndex2 < scores.count; ++uIndex2)
             {
                 GKScore* score = [scores objectAtIndex:uIndex2];

                 //score.date is out of the requested range at this point.
                 xEntry.m_uRank = static_cast<u_int> (score.rank);
                 xEntry.m_lScore = score.value;
                 xEntry.m_uContext = score.context;
             }
        }
    }];
}
```

I am doing all this in the sand box. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is there a statement somewhere from Apple when/why the timescopes in the GameCenter app/in-app widget were removed/deprecated? I can't find anything.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKGameCenterViewController I have seen more on it but I can't find it right now.

Comment: OK - it's funny how those leaderboards were deprecated in iOS7 and no one said anything, well, except you. :-) And I noticed as well. I haven't implemented any leaderboard interface myself anyway, just using the ones provided in iOS.